# Session issue between two tabs

Tags: java, session, web-applications

I have a java, j2EE based web application where on a page i am using session to store some of the data entered by the user due to some reasons. The page is used by an operator to fill data for a citizen.

Lets call that session attribute name as `attr1`.

The operator may try to fill multiple citizens data at once by opening a new tab on the browser. The session attribute `attr1` will obviously be shared between tabs and hence the entered data may not be correct when submitted.

I read somewhere that i can use html5 session storage as it is not shared between tabs. But using it makes the application browser dependent. The operator may try to use a non html5 compliant browser.

How do i solve this?

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp almost all recent browsers support session storage .
But you mixed up session attribute and cookie . Attributes are scoped in server side client will not know it.  When are you setting this cookie attr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put in an hidden input in the page a value like the timestamp generated in the back-end when the page is requested.
In this way every page will has a unique value.

Then you can put a hashmap in session where the key - value pairs are the generated timestamp (key) and the object you need (value).

When you submit the page you will get back the timestamp of the input hidden with the others parameter and you will be able to retrieve it from the map you put in the session the correct data!